# in "Lincoln felt that said attention to minutiae" sentence , how to interpret "said attention"?

Tags: verbs

In Manhattan prep,
I saw "Lincoln felt that said attention to minutiae, however necessary, had superseded more lofty goals." sentence.

1. I thought that the verb is felt but I confused how to interpret "said" next to felt. is subject of "said" Lincoln?

thank in advance.

Comment: "Said", in this sense, means "previously described".  Presumably the preceding context describes this "minutiae", and the attention it attracted.

Comment: ah thank so much ! you are right. preceding context describes same meaning. !

Comment: *aforementioned*